# SQL Long Decimal Value Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, decimal

So I have two identical values that are results of sum functions with the exact same length (no rounding is being done). (Update, data type is float)

Value_1 = 29.9539194336501
Value_2 = 29.9539194336501

The issue I'm having is when I do an IF statement for Value_1 = Value_2, it comes up as FALSE.

Value_1:

```
SELECT SUM([INVN_DOL])/SUM([AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS]) end as DSO
FROM TABLE A
```

Value_2:

```
SELECT SUM ([Total_Inventory_Val]) / SUM ([Daily_Independent_Demand])
FROM TABLE B
```

Any idea why they may not be exactly equal and what I can do to get a TRUE value since they do match?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure they are actually of same type and are equal? What happens when you cast them to `varbinary(8)`? (I assume you understand [how it works in principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683) and don't want to use [an epsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#comment3831071_588014)).

Comment: Tip: To add to the comment by GSerg, you can use [`SQL_Variant_Property()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql) to display the data type and related parameters, e.g. precision and scale, of an expression. For example: `select SQL_Variant_Property( ( SELECT SUM ([Total_Inventory_Val]) / SUM ([Daily_Independent_Demand])
FROM TABLE B ), 'BaseType' );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having here is that your are using a calculated value that is held within a `float`, which will by design be slightly imprecise at higher levels of precision, which is why you are getting your mismatch.

Use data types like `decimal` with a defined `precision` and `scale` to hold your values and calculation results and you should get consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

- You can make use [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) to limit the decimal points
  Or
- Try the [ABS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql) and see if that works out.